# StoryBoardと紐付けたUIパーツについて

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

StoryBoardから紐付けたUIパーツ(IBOutlet)はImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional型になりますが、紐付いているクラスをインスタンス化した後にはnilになることは無いということでしょうか？

Objective-CからSwiftへ移行していて、
今までは紐付けたUIパーツのframeの変更を行う場合、以下のように再度イニシャライズし、nilの場合を想定して対応していたのですがSwiftだとエラーになりました。

```
self.titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: 5, width: 70, height: 18))
```

もしnilになることが無ければ、以下のように値のみの変更で対応できると思うのですがどうなのでしょうか？

```
self.titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 8, y: 5, width: 70, height: 18)
```

Comment: どういうエラーが出るのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

[API Reference - UIView - addSubview(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622616-addsubview)

このDiscussionより引用すると、

> This method establishes a strong reference to view and sets its next responder to the receiver, which is its new superview.

Superviewは、Subviewを強参照しますから、`nil`になることはありません。それは、Storyboard/Interface Builderにおいて、Viewを配置した場合も同様です。

※Swift3より、**ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional型**は廃止になりました。

[Abolish ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional type](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md)

`!`のついた型は、自動UnwrapのオプションがついたOptional型であり、Optional型と異なる型ではない、ということです。

Comment: `titleLabel.removeFromSuperview()`を行なってもnilにならなくないでしょうか？Debug areaのVariables Viewで確認したのですが、nilにはならずアドレスを表示したままでした。

Comment: @shizukuruis 投稿なさった新規質問の方に、この件に関連した回答をいたしました。

Comment: @shizukuruis `removeFromSuperview()`の例を出すより、`addSubview()`を例にしたほうが、わかりやすいと思い、回答を書き換えました。